# sort data coming from my sql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, sorting

I have a video gallery where the data is coming from a mysql database.
I would like to give an option to sort the gallery in different ways: title, lecturer, date etc.

The first solution the comes into my mind is that when the user selects the different sort options (using option buttons) through ajax I would get the sorted data again from the databse and display using innerHTML.

Is this a good solution, is there any other nicer way to do this and avoid the database go-between?

I have to mention that the data is not in table format, each video is in it's own div. therefore would not be able to use the  jquery tablesorter

Thanks

Comment: the tablesorter plugin uses tables, maybe worth a look: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: You can create a JQuery function to sort your data regardless of which tag(s) the data is wrapped by.

Comment: @inhan can you give me some more direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to sort is to use database. There is no way in my knowledge to sort div.
So use ajax to sort.